# Is it bad practice to use normal variables in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react project, I need a variable that is dependent on two state variables. Do I need use useState for this variable, or only for the variables it is dependant on?

E.g. is this an acceptable design pattern:

```js
const [number1, setNumber1] = useState(2);
const [number2, setNumber2] = useState(2);
const sum = number1 + number2;
```

or do I need sum to be created as state and updated using useState (e.g. in a useEffect callback) whenever number1 or number2 changes?

Comment: In fact it's *good* practice. Keep your state minimal, and calculate derived values from that. [Documentation](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state)

Comment: If the calculation for `sum` were sufficiently complex, you might consider wrapping it in `const sum = React.useMemo(() => number1 + number2, [number1, number2])` to create a derived value that doesn't need recalculation on every render, but for a simple addition, this would be overkill and more complex/costly than your current approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just "acceptable", it's exactly what you *should* do!

Using an extra state and an effect to change it would be [considered inefficient and unncessary](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state) in fact:

> **When something can be calculated from the existing props or
> state, [don’t put it in state](https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-redundant-state).** Instead, calculate it
> during rendering. This makes your code faster (you avoid the extra
> “cascading” updates), simpler (you remove some code), and less
> error-prone (you avoid bugs
> caused by different state variables getting out of sync with each
> other). If this approach feels new to you, [Thinking in React](https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react#step-3-find-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state)
> explains what should go into state.

Comment: Thanks very much! I was looking for that part in the docs and must have missed it.